# I want to find the root z of the given equation in terms of c, where c is constant. How do I get it?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[(0.795+Sqrt[1+(-2.0656+z)*z]+0.5164*Log[1.03279556-z-Sqrt[1+ 
    (-2.0656+z)*z]]-0.5164*Log[1.03279556-z+Sqrt[1+(-2.0656+z)*z]])-c==0,z]
```

Comment: @Daniel Huber, the question has been modified, now you can look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Neither `Solve` nor `Reduce` can solve this problem symbolically.  Try solving it numerically using `FindRoot` for many values of `c`..  To obtain a rough idea of the values of the roots, first `Plot` the function.

Comment: I will help you to look at `Plot[(0.795 + Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z] + 
   0.5164*Log[1.03279556 - z - Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z]] - 
   0.5164*Log[1.03279556 - z + Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z]]), {z, -5, 
  5}]`

Comment: Please specify whether `c` is real.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, you can define an [`InverseFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html). Start by defining the function $c=f(z)$,

```
f[z_] = (0.795 + Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z] + 
        0.5164*Log[1.03279556 - z - Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z]] - 
        0.5164*Log[1.03279556 - z + Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z]]);
Plot[f[z], {z, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

This function has two branches, and so the inverse $z=\tilde{f}(c)$ sometimes jumps between two branches:

```
fi = InverseFunction[f];
Plot[fi[c], {c, -1, 5}]
```

[image]

To go further, as @bbgodfrey suggests, please indicate the constraints on $z$ and $c$.

Answer (score 2):

As you will have seen, Solve and Reduce do not work.

Let's have a look at your equation and let's write it using a function:

```
fun[z_]=(0.795+Sqrt[1+(-2.0656+z)z]+0.5164Log[1.03279556-z-Sqrt[1+(-2.0656+z)z]]-0.5164Log[1.03279556-z+Sqrt[1+(-2.0656+z)*z]])
```

You problem can now be written:

```
fun[z]==c
```

This can be solved by the inverse function of f. I assume you are looking for a real solutions. Let's plot fun to get an idea how it behaves. For large values of z z^2 in the square root will dominate and the function approximates a straight line for z-> +/- Infinity:

```
Plot[fun[z], {z, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

The interesting part seems to be around 1:

```
Plot[fun[z], {z, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

A piece seems to be missing. This is where the function becomes complex and this may be the reason for the problem with Solve and Reduce. But how to we now get the inverse function? Toward this aim we use "FunctionInterpolation", that gives us an "InterpolatingFunction", which we may try to invert. However we must take care that the inverse function is not multivalued.  We therefore split the range in 3 pieces, assuming a minimal/maximal value -5 and 10: {-5,0}, {0,0.76},{1.3,10}. The missing piece is where the fun is becomes complex:

```
Clear[fun1, fun2, fun3];
fun1[z_] = FunctionInterpolation[fun[z], {z, -5, 0}][z];
fun2[z_] = FunctionInterpolation[fun[z], {z, 0,0.76}][z];
fun3[z_] = FunctionInterpolation[fun[z], {z, 1.3, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 12][z];
```

Note we need to increase the recursion limit for fun3. We can now invert these functions. We do this numerically to prevent problems with non monotonic functions and multivalued functions:

```
Clear[ifun1, ifun2, ifun3];
ifun1[z_] = Interpolation[Table[{fun1[x], x}, {x, -5, 0, 0.1}]][z];
ifun2[z_] = Interpolation[Table[{fun2[x], x}, {x, 0, 0.76, 0.05}]][z];
ifun3[z_] = Interpolation[Table[{fun3[x], x}, {x, 1.3, 10, 0.1}]][z];
```

With  this we can now solve the original equation fun[z]==c. But note, as the total inverse functions can be multivalued, we need to decide which inverse functions we need. E.g. for c==2, we need ifun1 and ifun3::

```
{ifun1[#], ifun3[#]} &[2.]

(* {-3.95184, 1.40481} *)
```

Therefore for fun[z]==2 there are 2 solutions: z==-3.95184 and z==1.40481.

For c==0.4 wee need fun1 and fun2:

```
{ifun1[#], ifun2[#]} &[0.4]

{-1.75545, 0.738659}
```

Comment: Nice work!  Did you forget to include the definition of `eq` in your answer?

Comment: @Chris K Thank you for the hint, it should read fun[z], I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

We can get some idea of the solution by plotting `f` as a function of variable `z` and parameter `c`, highlighting `f==0` with `MeshFunctions`.

```
f := (0.795 + Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z] + 
     0.5164*Log[1.03279556 - z - Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z]] - 
     0.5164*Log[1.03279556 - z + Sqrt[1 + (-2.0656 + z)*z]]) - c;
Plot3D[f, {c, -1, 5}, {z, -8, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "z", "f"}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 0.5}]
```

[image: 3dplot of function]
That red curve is the solution, and as @DanielHuber and @Roman point out in their answers, it is both multi-valued and has a discontinuity.

Maybe it's easier to see in 2D:

```
ContourPlot[f == 0, {c, -1, 5}, {z, -8, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 FrameLabel -> {"c", "z"}, AspectRatio -> 0.6, ContourStyle -> Red]
```

[image: 2dplot]

Is visualizing the answer good enough, or do you need to extract the curve for further analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Two other simple ways to Plot `z` as a function of `c` are

```
ParametricPlot[{f[z], z}, {z, -8, 3}, AxesLabel -> {c, z}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 5}, Automatic}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

and (slightly less accurate at the discontinuity)

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{f[z], z}, {z, -8, 3, .0001}], AxesLabel -> {c, z}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 5}, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

both of which yield

[image: ![enter image description here]

Incidentally, the minimum value of `c` for which real roots of `f[z] == c` exist is

```
MinValue[{f[z], -1/2 < z < 1/2}, z]
(* -0.336118 *)
```